# Qualtrics required text entry to open-end box

Tags: qualtrics

What Javascript language would be most appropriate to require to enter text in the entry box if the option is one of the options selected from the list of options?

Comment: `JavaScript` *is* a language...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned already, you don't need to use javascript.

Here is an example:
[image: How to require text entry box]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript. Right click on the answer option then select Text Entry Validation/Force Response.